# Caroufredsel showing partial images

Tags: javascript, caroufredsel

My caroufredsel carousel is showing 8 images at a time and then sliding across the screen to show another 8. However, for the first four times the carousel slides, a partial image on the right shows instead of a complete image. After four slides, the carousel snaps to where it is supposed to be and show all images correctly from then on. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a setting I need to use that I've missed? 
Here is the link.

http://dev.mattresstime.co.uk/cheapbeds/mattresstime/index.php

This is the jQuery

```
$j("#manufacturer_list").carouFredSel({ 
    width:904,  
    height: 81,
    items: {
        visible: 8,
        minimum: 1,         
        width: 113,
        height: 81
    },
    scroll: {
        pauseOnHover: true
    },
    swipe: {
        onTouch  : true,
        onMouse  : true
    },   
    prev : "#prev_button",
    next : "#next_button"
});
```